# What to do with missing fields in sunspot-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm using sunspot/rails version 2.  It's working great, but I can't figure out how to handle missing fields.  If I don't have latitude and longitude this code will map it to 0,0 (near Africa):

```
searchable do
  text      :resume, :stored => true
  text      :city, :boost => 5
  latlon(:geo) { Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(latitude, longitude) }
end
```

I tried using two search blocks, each with a different conditional, but sunspot just uses the first searchable block.  What I want to happen is for things missing locations to still be searchable, just not by location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes usually I have an if check after the optional condition:

```
searchable do
  text      :resume, :stored => true
  text      :city, :boost => 5
  latlon(:geo) { Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(latitude, longitude) } if latitude && longitude
  # other conditions if needed
  with(:another_field, condition_var) if condition_var
end
```

Comment: I can't find "when" in the sunspot docs. Do you know where to find it?

Comment: sorry it should have been `with`.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of a workaround, adding a boolean field called `has_location` or something, and then always checking that when doing a geo search.  Kludgy but it should work.